# A forum for students?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know of a forum like this one but for students of economics rather than professionals? For instance there are two Stackexchange math. forums, one for everbody and one for professional mathematicians?

Comment: I've voted for this question to be moved over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take some time to browse the site, you will find out that in reality it deals more with issues that interest students rather than professional and academic economists and analysts.

Comment: However a lot of trivial student questions get downvoted (by me) and closed. Whereas on [math.SE] sometimes even trivial questions are answered and accepted.

Comment: @denesp Granted (and well-done IMHO). But even after we purge the site from closed questions, what remains looks more I believe like study-level (perhaps higher), than research-level. Of course, if the OP meant an on-line problem-solver or student-assistant, he won't find it here.